# Storing custom collection templates in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

### Background

I'm developing a web application that requires users to create and fill in custom tables (think HTML or MS Word tables, not database tables). The idea is that admins will create the templates for those tables, and general users will fill them in. Each general user can fill their own template, so there will be many tables that use the same template.

Now, these templates can hold any amount of columns, and each column can have a different data type. They can also change over time, meaning there should be versions of them. In other words, once a user fills a template, it should be stored with that structure, even if the template changes in the future. It will keep the old version of the template, while new users will use the newest version.

I usually work with relational databases, but for this scenario, a relational database doesn't seem like a good fit. I feel would end up with a bunch of tables and require many joins to extract the data I need, especially if the database is normalized.

I thought about using something like MongoDB. I'm new to Mongo, so I'm sure I haven't explored every single option, but I thought it would be better idea than using MySQL (what I've used for other apps). Do tell me if I'm wrong about this, though; maybe I'm missing something.

I want to be able to store the templates (name, columns (in order, with their names and data types)), then reuse these templates every time a user wants to fill them in. I would use a collection to store all tables that use the same template version. That is, a collection would be created each time a template is made. The collection should have defined data types that all documents inside should follow. If I'm understanding correctly, MongoDB offers schema validation for this.

### My approach and questions

1. How can I store templates in the database? I thought about storing them as documents in a "templates" collection, which would be something like the example below, but I'm concerned about having the data types as strings.

   ```
   {
       name: <String>,
       fields: [
           {
               name: <String>,
               type: <String>    <----this is what I have an issue with
           },
           ...
       ]
   }
   ```

   I would have to read these templates and convert their structure into HTML tables so users can fill them, then store them as documents in the collections with the template name or id.

   Something like:

   ```
   {
       template_id: <uuid, integer, string or something>
       name: <String>,
       rows: [
           {
               <field name>:<field value of specified type>,
               ...
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. How feasible and recommendable is it to create collections on the fly?

If anything is unclear, let me know so I can clarify. Like I said, I'm new to MongoDB (and non-relational DBs in general), so if I'm missing something obvious, feel free to point it out and offer suggestions. Helpful links to the docs or tutorials are also welcome. I'm also open to trying other NoSQL solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same idea about storing templates in mongodb in my application. 
You should using a standard schema for your project because we will have some  support library for validate data.

1. **JSON Schema**:
   Current version is draft-07 http://json-schema.org/
   .You can read about the schema standard and have client library in many program language
2. **MongoDB**:
   Now MongoDB 3.6 support validate JSon Schema draft-04
   https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/#json-schema
3. **Storing Schema in MongoDB**:
   We will have problem when store Json schema in a colletion. 
   Json Schema has some characters which can't store in mongodb.
   You can reference https://accraze.info/storing-json-schema-templates-in-mongodb/